# Is there a way to add searchable tags to individual pages of a PDF?

Tags: pdf, tags

Similar to the way Youtube videos are tagged, I would like to be add tags to individual pages in a PDF based on what they're about. Ideally it would work so that if I tag a page "apple orange banana strawberry lemon" and I search for "banana lemon" then that page will come up (ie the search terms don't need to be in the correct order for the result to be displayed).

Is there any way I can do this or am I stuck with what I've got?

Comment: There are many different clients that can be used to read a PDF, and it is unlikely you would find a way to do this that worked consistently across all of them.  Some will already do what you want, if they have a search function that says "search for pages containing all terms"